# How to list dependencies of c/c++ static library?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

For a static library (.a file), how to list the module-level dependencies of it?

I know for a shared library (.so), we can use *objdump* or *readelf* to do this:

```
objdump -p test.so
```

or

```
readelf -d test.so
```

I can get something like

> NEEDED               libOne.so
>
> NEEDED               libc.so.6

But for a static library, I can only get the dependencies in symbol-level, for example, by running

```
objdump -T test.a
```

I will get some thing like:

> 00000000      DF *UND*    00000000 QByteArray::mid(int, int) const
>
> 00000000      DF *UND*    00000000 QUrl::fromEncoded(QByteArray const&)
>
> 00000000      DF *UND*    00000000 QFileInfo::fileName() const

But I need the information in module-level, does anyone know how to get that information?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A static library *have* no such list of dependencies.

A static library is nothing more than an archive of object files. And as object files doesn't know what libraries they depend on, neither can a static library.

Comment: I'd say the reason for this is that static library is not **linked**. Therefore, no one in the build chain so far was responsible for adding such information to it.

Comment: @Jan Smrčina @Some programmer dude But how can a static library be generated without knowing that information? For example, library A uses a function defined in another library B. If we don't add something like `#include "B.h"`, can A be generated? In that case, can we say A depends on B?

Comment: @bagebb Just like any other object file. The `ar` command used to create static libraries is a plain and very simple *ARchiver*. For static libraries it's up to you to keep track of the dependencies, and link with them explicitly. It's nothing that the linker is capable of, all it does is basically to extract the object files and link with them.

Comment: @Some programmer dude So does it mean for the case I mentioned above, if I don't specify `#include "B.h"`, static library A can still be created, but if I want to use A to generated an executable, I have to link to B somewhere?

Comment: @bagebb That's correct. In fact, the header files have nothing to do with it.

Comment: It is 2024, and in _binutils_ version 2.40, the `ar` tool can record dependencies in any `.a` file. See the documantation for `ar`, in particular the `l` (l for Lima) operation code modifier.

Answer (score 3):

@Some programmer dude is right, but what you can do is build a simple program using this library statically and then check with `ldd -v`  what are the dependencies.

Comment: This is helpful.  The hard part though is building it because you would have to know all the dependencies to specify them at build time, so you already have this information, or you would be in the same predicament.  'ldd -v' would be useful to inspect applications that someone else built, but I'd say that if you have something built statically in-hand, your fastest path is the ask the person who built it what the dependencies are.