# Getting external static library in CMake

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

I have a static library `A` that depends on other shared libraries `B` and `C`. When I build my application `D`, I need to find and link with `A`, `B` and `C`. Is there a way to tell CMake to link only with `A` and to get from it that it needs to link with `B` and `C`?

Note that the application `A` is a different project with it's own CMake files and directories and that all of the libraries and the application are for Linux.

Comment: There is a way to do it, its called "modern CMake" https://schneide.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/modern-cmake-with-target_link_libraries/

Comment: @R2RT I read this solution before but a far as I understand it will work only within the same project. If the application is a complete separate project with it's own CMake files and directories I think that this will not work.

I will modify my question to make it more clear

Comment: As long as A's CMakeLists.txt follows modern CMake it will work. If it does not follow them it will make you link its dependencies (B and C) anyway via compiler flags.

Comment: Unlike to shared libraries, static libraries don't contain information about their linkage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789518/how-to-list-dependencies-of-c-c-static-library. So, if CMake knows nothing aside from the static library *A*, then it is unable to get *B* and *C* as its dependencies.

Comment: @R2RT I tried it and it's not sufficient by it's own. It need project `A` to be exported and imported from project `D` for this solution to work. The other solution I am trying now is to create a package for this library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes this is correct. I search for a solution in which CMake can store some extra information to be used by the application project CMake. Creating a package do this and seems to be a good solution for me.